# Matlab/Octave: How to resize a .mat file? Reduce resolution of data for smaller file/data set size

Tags: matlab, octave, netcdf

I have a Matlab data set file which contains data for a grid `[X , Y]`. I would like to reduce the resolution of the data set file to `[P , Q]`, where `P = X / scale` and `Q = Y / scale`. So for example if the data set is originally `1400 x 800` and I want to scale it down by a factor of `10` I will get a new data set file with resolution `140 x 80`. How would this be done in Matlab and/or Octave?

If instead there is an easy way to convert Matlab (*.mat) files into `NetCDF` then I can easily take it from there, please reference if so (I haven't found anything using basic Google search). I'm aware of `ncwrite` but there's a catch-22 of sorts with that because I can't read the data in the first place because the .mat file is too large for my environment (I'm trying to avoid building Octave for 64-bit address space, and instead use a smaller data set while doing development).

I'm using Octave on Windows now, so I'd prefer to pull this off with Octave or another non-Matlab tool, but I may have access to a proper Matlab version soon.

Comment: Please read the first line from the mat file, is it v7.3 or one of the older versions? You can open it in any text editor which can handle the size, or use `fopen` / `fgetl` in octave to get the text content of the first line.

Comment: Do you need any interpolation done to get the scaled matrix, or do you just want to take, for example, every 10th row/column?

Comment: @beaker his problem is not on scaling the data. His problem is that he is unable to load the whole dataset into memory because it has more elements than what can be indexed with a 32-bit int (he's using Octave built with 32-bit indexing).

Comment: @carandraug Ah, so the scaling was to occur *before* reading. I understand now.

Comment: Thanks for these comments and suggestions. I want to read a smaller amount of data from the file so as to not overload the memory of the smallish machine I'm using for this development work (thanks for clarifying this @beaker). I'm not actually scaling the data as I'm subsampling (I think that is a more apt description?) in order to read in a smaller data set, sorry for using 'scale' in the question above as that's misleading as to what I'm actually trying to accomplish. @Daniel the header shows MATLAB 7.0 MAT-file, Platform: GLNXA64, Created on: Mon Oct 19 11:16:00 2015 HDF5 schema 0.05

Comment: I think I want to do what's available via Matlab's matlab.io.MatFile object, i.e. get every 10th row/column of data from variable named precip, like this:  data = matfile('myfile.m').precip(:10:, :10:);

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way I can think of is by dividing the original vectors/matrices from the .math file by the scale you want, apply a rounding function and, finally, the unique() function.

For example:

```
octave:1> x=1:20
x =

 Columns 1 through 16:

    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16

 Columns 17 through 20:

   17   18   19   20

octave:2> y = round(x/4)
y =

   0   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   3   3   3   3   4   4   4   4   5   5   5

octave:3> unique(y)
ans =

   0   1   2   3   4   5
```

Comment: his problem is not on scaling the data. His problem is that he is unable to load the whole dataset into memory because it has more elements than what can be indexed with a 32-bit int (he's using Octave built with 32-bit indexing).

Comment: I see. Maybe he can just load each element from the .mat one at a time, divide by the scale, apply the rounding, and keep only the new elements.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not actually scaling, wrong use of that term for in my original question, sorry for the confusion. Basically I want to read in every nth element, so as to not overwhelm the memory space of 32-bit Octave. For example I want to read in data for every 10th column and every 10th row. If there's a tool out there that lets you permute the dimensions of a Matlab file (such as NCO for NetCDF files) then I can use that, or there may be a way in Octave to read in a subsample of data values from a big Matlab file, and if so then that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Well, as far as I know matlab won't load the entire .mat file as soon as you call it. It waits for you to actually need it. Check out this link: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/load-parts-of-variables-from-mat-files.html

Comment: I'm using Octave, @DanielSevero, if I was able to use Matlab then I doubt that I'd have this issue. For example I could use matlab.io.matfile as described in another of my comments above, and/or maybe Matlab is 64-bit by default and can read my full size file without choking as does 32-bit Octave.